# React warning: contains an input of type hidden with value and default value - how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm a total newbie to React (started using it barely a week ago) and I don't have the requisite knowledge to figure this warning out. I have 2 sets of select boxes (materialUI) - so in all there are 4 select boxes. The first set of select boxes are displayed all the time. The second set of select boxes are displayed CONDITIONALLY - if 'Brazil' is selected in the second select(countrySelection select box) in the original set of select boxes, the next second set of hidden select boxes are displayed but I get the warning (posted below the code) about controlled and uncontrolled input elements.

```
//these are the event handler functions
        handleCategorySwitch = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value});

    console.log(`name ${name}, value ${value}`);
}


//this is the sub-selection
handleSubselection = (e) => {
    this.setState({RptSecondInput: e.target.value, isLoading: true })
    switch( e.target.value) {
        case 'input3':
        return  this.props.GetAllCountries()
    }

}

//this calls the reducer function ReportGetAllCountries
handleReportSwitch = (e) => {
    let selectedName = e.target.name
    const selectedValue = e.target.value;
this.setState({[selectedName]:selectedValue })
    if (selectedValue == 'USA') {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            report: 'states',
            isLoading: true
        }), this.props.ReportGetAllCountries)
    }   

   //if selected value is Brazil, the countries report is set
    if (selectedValue == 'Brazil') {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            report: 'countries'
        }))

       }
     }





      const {filename, isLoading, countries, stateSelection, 
        countrySelection, 
       isReportSelected, RptFirstInput, RptSecondInput} = this.state;

    return (
       <div className="reports">
            {this.placeholder()}

            <div className="selectInputRow flexMode">
                <div className="selectInput">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="stateSelection">Category: 
         </InputLabel>
            //I have two sets of select boxes - these are the first two
                    <Select value={stateSelection} name={'stateSelection'} 
           onChange={(e) => this.handleCategorySwitch(e)} 
            className="fixedWidth">

                        <MenuItem value={'None'} >Select Category</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'State1'}>Cat 1</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'State2'}>Cat 2 </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'State3'}>Cat 3 </MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </div>
                <div className="selectInput">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="countrySelection">Report Name: 
             </InputLabel>
              //the warning happens when I select 'Brazil' in this select 
                 box
                    <Select value={countrySelection} name="countrySelection" 
              onChange={(e) => this.handleReportSwitch(e)} 
                className="fixedWidth" >
                        <MenuItem value={'None'}>Select Report</MenuItem>
                        {reports && reports.map((report, index) => <MenuItem 
              key={index} value={report.actOn}>{report.name}</MenuItem>)}   
                    </Select>
                </div>
            </div>

            { this.state.report === 'countries' ?  (
                <div className="selectInputRow">

                <div className="selectInput">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="RptFirstInput">Input 1: 
                    </InputLabel>

                    <Select name="RptFirstInput" value={RptFirstInput} 
                  placeholder={'Select field'}  className="fixedWidth"   
                    // onChange={(e) => this.handleSubselection(e)}
                    >
                        <MenuItem value={'Default'}>Select</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'Country'}>Country</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'Region'}>Region</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'Zone'}>Zone</MenuItem>
                    </Select>

                </div>
                <div className="selectInput">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="RptSecondInput">Input 2: 
                      </InputLabel>

                    <Select name="RptSecondInput" defaultValue= 
                     {RptSecondInput} value={RptSecondInput}  
          className="fixedWidth"   onChange={(e) => 
                 this.handleSubselection(e)}>
                        <MenuItem value={'Def'}>Select</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'input2'}>Input 2</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'input3'}>Input 3</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'input4'}>Input 4</MenuItem>
                    </Select>

                </div>
            </div>
            ) : null}


            <div className="iconDownload">


                {isLoading
                ? <CircularProgress /> 
                : (
                    <Table id="t1">
                        <TableHeaders data={this.csvHeader()} />
                        <TableContent data={this.csvData()} />
                    </Table>
                )}

            </div>
        </div>
        )
       }
```

The warning that I get is the following:

```
    Warning: ForwardRef(SelectInput) contains an input of type hidden with 
    both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either 
    controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the 
    defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or 
    uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props. More info: 
    https:fb.  me react-controlled-components
    in input (created by ForwardRef(SelectInput))
     in ForwardRef(SelectInput) (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
```

Comment: @DennisVash He's provided more than enough code to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in this input:

```js
<Select 
  name="RptSecondInput" 
  defaultValue={RptSecondInput} 
  value={RptSecondInput}  
  className="fixedWidth"   
  onChange={(e) => this.handleSubselection(e)}>
    <MenuItem value={'Def'}>Select</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'input2'}>Input 2</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'input3'}>Input 3</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'input4'}>Input 4</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Remove the `defaultValue` prop.

Answer (score 1):

The React documentation has a couple of useful details about [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (that link specifically focuses on forms) and [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

In short, by setting the `value` prop on the `input`, you are “controlling” the component—it's value is not dependent on user input, but instead on the value of the `value` prop. A controlled component typically needs an event listener, like `onChange`, that will update the value of the `value` prop.

If you instead prefer to let the value of the input be determined by the user input without using an event (an “uncontrolled” component), but you want to provide an initial value, React offers the `defaultValue` prop. This will set the `value` of the input initially, but user input will alter the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs must be either [controlled or uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Specifying a `defaultValue` prop turns your input in controlled and uncontrolled at the same time (it's state has two sources of truth). To specify a default value of a controlled input you must define it as the initial value of the state which holds the input.

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState('default')

    return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
}
```